# How do I make my array query into a string query in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

Due to the way I have set up my template, I need to have the following in a string url format:

```
$the_query = array( 'post_type' => 'product', 'taxonomy' => 'product_types', 'term' => 'solar-panel' )
```

I thought something like

```
$the_query = new WP_Query( 'post_type=product&taxonomy=product_types&term=solar-panel&showposts=2' )
```

but this isn't working due to the fact that taxonomy is an array in itself.  Thanks.

Comment: its ok it is actually working, my mistake

Answer (score 0):

Will your template allow you to set your options outside of WP_Query?

```
$args=array(
  'post_type' => 'product',
  'taxonomy' => 'product_types',
  'term' => 'solar-panel',
);

$the_query = new WP_Query($args);
```

If not, what about your template won't allow you to do this? Could you post some code?

Comment: it's ok, I managed to do it in the string format.  I think I was thinking that if I done it the way you've posted then I would have to do a foreach loop, but I don't do I?  It can still be a <?php while ($the_query -> have_posts()) : $the_query -> the_post(); ?>